# What is the correct way to distribute bespoke iphone apps?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod-touch

I have developed a few app store applications but recently have been asked by small and medium companies if I would be interested in developing bespoke apps.

I find the license and contracts with Apple a little confusing to say the least, there are 3 types of build a developer can produce.

1. App store
2. Ad Hoc
3. Enterprise

App store is not required as these are private projects.  Ad Hoc seems to be limited to 100 pre-identified devices which again isn't ideal and Enterprise is for 250+ applications? So how can you develop an app for the iphone with an unknown number of client installs from say 50 to 150?

I want to give the client the app (ipa) and let them control who they give/sell it too, is this even possible?

Thanks for any advice

Geoff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need an enterprise account to do this. There you can compile distribution builds that can be installed on any iphone/ipad you want without having to include them in a list as for ad hoc builds.

Comment: Ah thanks.  I have just read the Apple docs on the Enterprise program and they have greatly improved it since I last looked.  Thanks again.